# Find out what is locking a MySQL InnoDB table-row

Tags: mysql

I use a database with an InnoDB-table. When I try to update a row, I get the "ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" message, which I don't get on any other row (that I've tried).

How can I debug that?

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

is only yielding sleeping processes and because it's an InnoDB table, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is basically useless (seems to work only for MyISAM tables).

> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

also does not contain anything useful; the LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK section contains two transactions from 3 days ago that no longer exist (thread IDs no longer appear in SHOW PROCESSLIST) and no longer seem relevant.

Is there any way to get to know what query caused the problem?
Also I would love to see the current locks on InnoDB tables, what is locking what right now - and not three days ago.

Comment: One question, is this error occuring at the same time or is it random? Is it part of a event maybe? Do you have error handling in the SP (which i assume is what you execute?)

Comment: Did the problem go away?

Comment: Kay, I fixed the problem by killing the process. I don't know how it happened and it seems to be one of these very rare strange bugs that appear only once a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the error log file of mysql? Maybe there is more detail to which transaction it is that failed.

To show all tables that are in use, simply execute this syntax

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE IN_Use=1
```

Comment: This only shows the current session tables that is in use.

Comment: SHOW OPEN TABLES lists the non temp tables that are currently open in the table cache.